# how to setup pptp vpn server on archlinux?

Tags: vpn, archlinux, ppp

I followed the instruction on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PPTP_Server to setup the pptp vpn server with pptpd.

After everything is done, I cannot connect to the server. I found that there is not any ppp virtual adapter in `ifconfig`'s output. But there is no error in log of pptpd service, and pptpd process is running.

The log of client is below:

```
Apr 06 09:31:34 root pppd[540]: Using interface ppp1
Apr 06 09:31:34 root pppd[540]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/3
Apr 06 09:31:34 root pptp[541]: anon log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Apr 06 09:31:35 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Apr 06 09:31:35 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Apr 06 09:31:35 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 0).
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pptp[546]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pppd[540]: Modem hangup
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pppd[540]: Connection terminated.
Apr 06 09:31:36 root pppd[540]: Exit.
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it? THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a typo in /etc/ppp/option.pptpd. After correcting it, the server worked.